# Can't document parameter of class method out of line

Tags: c++, doxygen

After writing a documentation in following format:

```
/*! \class Bishop
 *  \brief Child class of Figure representing Bishop.
 *
 *  \fn Bishop::Bishop()
 *  \brief Defualt constructor.
 *  \param [in] color Which player owns this chess piece.
 *
 *  \fn virtual bool Bishop::CanMoveTo(const Board * board, int x, int y) const
 *  \brief Whether currently selected chess piece can move to coordinates given in parameters.
 *  \param[in] board Chess board figure belongs to.
 *  \param[in] x X coordinate to move to.
 *  \param[in] y Y coordinate to move to. 
 *  \return True if such move is possible, else false.
 *
 *  \fn virtual string Bishop::Description() const
 *  \brief Name of chess piece.
 *  \return "bishop".
 */

class Bishop : public Figure
{
    public:
        Bishop(color_t color);
        virtual bool CanMoveTo(const Board * board, int x, int y) const;
        virtual std::string Description() const;
};
```

I get following error from doxygen:

```
bishop.h:14: warning: The following parameters of Bishop::CanMoveTo(const Board *board, int x, int y) const are not documented:
  parameter 'board'
```

I've had a same parameter `const Board * board` in different classes and documentation was generated without any problems. Am I missing something here?

Comment: When I document it as a third parameter (not first), it works. Weird.

Comment: Sorry my guess didn't work. I deleted it in order not to confuse anyone and because you changed that part in your question (so it would look unrelated).

Comment: @Oguk It's okay. I don't really need to solve this problem anymore, but I would assume it was simply a bug in Doxygen.